# How to open VSCODE with new file from command line and preserve prior state?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Using Visual Studio Code (latest version as well as prior versions), when using the command line to launch I am seeing some odd behavior.  Trying to determine if I am missing something, or if this is a bug.

Here is the scenario.

**Action 1**: I have a workspace open with a couple of files open for editing.  If I close VSCODE, and then just open it again the state is restored, I am in the workspace and the files are open for editing.  Great.

**Action 2**: I have a workspace open with a couple of files open for editing.  If I then from a command line do "vscode testfile.txt" then the new file gets opened in VSCODE and joins the other opened file.  Great.

**Action 3**: I have a workspace open with a couple of files open for editing.  I close VSCODE.  I then from a command line do "vscode testfile.txt".  VSCODE starts up, but only the new file gets opened in VSCODE.  The workspace I had opened is not any more, and the files I had opened are no longer opened.  Not so great.

I have tried adding the -r option on the command line but that didn't change anything.

This feels like a bug, but if not help me understand how I get the desired result, which is when VSCODE is not running, and I try to edit a file from the command line, I want VSCODE to restore to the state it was in when last closed, and then add that new file to the mix.  Just like if it was already running.

Comment: `from a command line do "vscode testfile.txt". VSCODE starts up, but only the new file gets opened in VSCODE` I'm not sure I could agree that's a bug since you told it to only open a file, if you want it to open at dir level you can use `code .` vscode only perserves workspace configs/layout states afaik

Comment: To qualify my remarks, you can open many files using CLI `code file1.txt file2.txt`, or many folders, and you can do a mixture of files and folders, but when you do this it will override the state since it's technically a new state because you told it to. Might be worth posting on their github as a feature request, unless I'm totally in left field here and someone helps

Comment: I guess as is often the case there can be multiple interpretations.  From the command line docs I see:
*-n or --new-window Opens a new session of VS Code instead of restoring the previous session (default).*
*-r or --reuse-window Forces opening a file or folder in the last active window.*
I understand **-n**, that makes sense, but your interpretation is that having a file (or folder) on the command line also forces this behavior.  But for the **-r** it doesn't seem to have any affect.  If VSCODE is already open, then opening a file from the CLI always opens it in the current VSCODE window.

Comment: And it opens it in the current window with or without the **-r**, so that seems to be a useless option.  I guess I'll report this as a bug/feature and see what the VSCODE folks have to say, unless I get something else useful here...